# Настройка DKIM для домена

Tags: postfix, рассылка, спам, dkim

Установил postfix вопрос как настроить DKIM я так понял там нужна пара ключей, в описании почты для домена яндекса понятно заходишь в определённый раздел - https://yandex.ru/support/pdd/set-mail/dkim.xml вот и подпись, вставляешь её в TXT-запись домена в DNS. А если я сам себе почтовый сервер:
1) где взять пару ключ-значение?
2) Куда её потом в postfix вставлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно установить opendkim. Его конфигурационный файл - `/etc/opendkim.conf`.

Для создания ключей используется команда `opendkim-genkey -t -s mail -d <ваш_домен>`. Выполнив её вы получите два файла - *.private (с приватным ключом) и *.txt (с публичной записью, которую нужно будет добавить в настройки домена). В параметре **KeyFile** конфигурационного файла вам нужно указать полный путь к *.private файлу, а в параметре **Selector** - то, что вы указывали в параметре `-s` команды opendkim-genkey.

Что бы сказать Postfix'у про то, что вы теперь используете DKIM, вам нужно задать в его конфигурационном файле (вероятно `/etc/postfix/main.cf`) строку вроде `smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891`. Значение этого параметра должно соответствовать параметру **Socket** из конфигурации opendkim. Для данного примера это должна быть запись `Socket inet:8891@localhost`.

Не забудьте добавить opendkim в автозагрузку и обновить конфигурацию Postfix'а через `postfix reload`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно установить OpenDKIM и ключи самому создать.

Не знаю стоит ли подробно расписывать здесь, т.к. и [в дебиан вики](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/opendkim) и [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/151904/) есть уже статьи по postfix и opendkim.